# Textools - Create UV Mesh Use Cases?

Tags: modeling, add-on, edit-mode

I am browsing some possibilities of the amazing add-on 'Textools' and I cannot understand what would be the benefit of using the 'Create UV Mesh' tool in Mesh UV Tools?

Couldn't find a clue to what one could use it for anywhere online, would anyone be able to assist with some examples?

Thanks so much

[image]

Comment: That appears to be a third-party addon, not part of Blender. Have you looked on the addon's web site [here](http://renderhjs.net/textools/blender/) for instance?

Comment: I did, I know what it does but my question is.. What would you use it for

Comment: You'd have to ask the addon author that one!

Comment: that is something I've seen people creating around the web, not only with textools, they explain how to do it but not what for

Comment: Often used for texture painting. There's a very quick explanation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9nE2Xg6Jgk) for Blender 2.8, but it's the same for most versions.

Comment: I used to use it to wrap a flat pattern mesh around another mesh: flatten, surface deform bind to flattened mesh, unflatten.  Also found it useful to reverse engineer clothing patterns from clothing, for cloth physics.  But now, I use GN techniques to do the same thing, rather than TexTools.

Comment: Thanks you, I did think about the texture paint but than.. why won't you just paint the uvs? I do like the reverse engineering of the clothing patterns!